# How do I find the complement of an array?

Tags: arrays

If I have a sorted array of numerical values such as `Double`, `Integer`, and `Time`, what is the general logic to finding a complement?

Over my CS career in college, I've gotten better of understanding complements and edge cases for ranges. As I help students whose skill levels and understanding match mine when I wrote this, I need help finding a generalized way to convey this concept to them for singular elements and ranges.

Comment: `if my_list == [1,3,5,7,10]: return [2,4,6,8,9]`

Comment: This is very confusing as you get the + of every number apart from the 10.

Comment: Let me clarify, how I can iterate through a list and find the missing components?

Comment: @JDSmith, Although we have chosen to answer the implied question, please try to make your question more specific in the future.

Comment: @merlin2011 Why did you choose to answer such a poorly defined question? None of the answers take the same approach, some of them have wildly different results and approaches.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, Because if we ignore all questions just because they are poorly written, we will not encourage new users to ask questions.

Comment: ***We should not encourage this type of question.*** This user has shown no effort into even writing a specification for what they need, let alone what they have tried, yet this still got 5 answers.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr There is no "encouraging". The vote number gives an indication of the quality of the question but you can still choose to answer. There are even badges for this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, I cannot argue with that. Sometimes I make the decision to answer a question without considering whether it creates the right incentives. See [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265924/391161).

Comment: Or you can just spam the down-vote buttons for all the answers to a question you believe doesn't deserve to be answered in an attempt to sway your opinion onto others.

Comment: I don't believe any of the answers actually answer the question. Under my interpretation of the question the complement of a list would be a list containing every element not in the first list.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr you are correct. My answer was not defining the second   required set.

Comment: I have thrown my hat in the ring for silliest answer, most over specced answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def complement(l, universe=None):
    """
    Return the complement of a list of integers, as compared to
    a given "universe" set. If no universe is specified,
    consider the universe to be all integers between
    the minimum and maximum values of the given list.
    """
    if universe is not None:
        universe = set(universe)
    else:
        universe = set(range(min(l), max(l)+1))
    return sorted(universe - set(l))
```

then

```
l =  [1,3,5,7,10]
complement(l)
```

yields:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Or you can specify your own universe:

```
complement(l, range(12))
```

yields:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the compliment of two lists using list comprehension. Here we are taking the complement of a set `x` with respect to a set `y`:

```
>>> x = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10]
>>> y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 20]
>>> z = [n for n in x if not n in y]
>>> z
[5, 7, 10]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add another option - using a data type that is always useful to learn about, for these types of operations.

```
a = set([1, 3, 5, 7, 10])
b = set(range(1, 11))
c = sorted(list(b.symmetric_difference(a)))
print(c)

[2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> nums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10]
>>> [n + ((n&1)*2-1) for n in nums]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I'm interested to know the reason for downvoting so I can improve my answer

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this came to me in a review queue.  I'd guess someone didn't like the code only answer (tend to get some people downvoting here - with 43k rep I guess you know that). I guess here, the `n&1` is a bit cryptic for some people, so the downvoter probably wanted explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to iterate from the beginning of your list to the second to last element. Set `j` equal to the `index + 1`. While `j` is less than the next number in your list, append it to your list of complements and increment it.

```
# find the skipped numbers in a list sorted in ascending order
def getSkippedNumbers (arr):
    complement = []
    for i in xrange(0, len(arr) - 1):
        j = arr[i] + 1
        while j < arr[i + 1]:
            complement.append(j)
            j += 1
    return complement

test = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10]
print getSkippedNumbers(test) # returns [2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```